# Why can't I use 'require' with 'array_map'?

Tags: php

I've tried to include the contents from a list of files:

```
$files = [
    'a.php',
    'b.php',
];
$contents = array_map('require', $files);
```

But this didn't work. The error I get is:

> Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'require' not found or invalid function name

Why is this and is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because require isn't a function, it's a language construct.

You'll need to create a valid callback function to do the actual require, or use an autoloader

Comment: Little side note here: Because require is a language construct it also doesn't need parentheses e.g. `require "test.php"` is completely valid without the brackets, but you can also do it with brackets

Answer (score 1):

As everyone already noticed - it is a language construct.

You can try this

```
$includes = array('a.php', 'b.php');

array_map(function($file){
        require $file;
}, $includes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Mark Baker as it's not function , You can use _autoload() in case you are including class files.

Comment: `__autoload()` has two underscores at the beginning, not one

Answer (score 0):

```
use autoload or spl_autoload_register 
to comfort work use namespaces
or you may use array_wallk without return value and anonunys function
`$files` = [
'a.php',
    'b.php',
];
`$contents` = array_map(`$files`, function(`$el`){
require(`$el`);
});

//but foreach working faster:

foreach(`$files` as `$item`){
require(`$item`


);}`
```

Comment: I don't think these backticks should be in the code